# Mendeley would not work after last Ubuntu Update

Tags: 14.04, qt, mendeley

I have a mendeley running on Ubuntu 14.04.5. I am having issues starting the software now after an update a few weeks ago. I receive this error message:

> /usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/mendeleydesktop: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/qt/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5)
>
> /usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/bin/mendeleydesktop: relocation error: /usr/bin/../../opt/mendeleydesktop/lib/qt/libQt5WebEngineCore.so.5: symbol _ZNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEED1Ev, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference

Could anyone help with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ver 1.18 of Mendeley and come back to ver 1.17.3.
I did it and it's working now